# distriqt nativemaps- Error w AIR 16

Tags: sdk, maps, ane, linkoption

When debugging USB using Apache Flex Compiled SDK - 14.16.16 I get the following error:

> Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> ld: can't open -non_global_symbols_no_strip_list file:
>   /Users/CRMantra/AIR_14.16.16/lib/aot/lib/local_nostrip.arm-air.txt
>   Compilation failed while executing : ld64

__________ Found this relating to the platform.xml used in compiling the ANE. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1220219

I have two questions:

1) I need the permissions for the Maps to throw a NativeDialog box using the requestLocationAuthorization(true) - so User will set permission normally.

2) Whats the recommended and tested SDK version for this ANE. Also, have you been able to set permissions via a Dialog Box from tested SDK? From my reading AIR 16 is the recommended version to set permissions and get around the Geo Object always muted issue. I did notice that NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true; will fix the Geo.mute issue as well, but it still needs the above mentioned Native Dialog Box, and it requires user to set Privacy/Maps each run of the .ipa

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 0):

I found if you copy the SDK to another location and dereference any symbolic links that the issue disappears.

i.e.

```
cp -RLf /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk SOME_OTHER_LOCATION
```